# Do not show suggestions when Search bar empty using Angular 4 Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have backend server that provides me information regarding Furniture. I have a Frontend service in Angular (Typescript) where a user will type in related words and the service suggests similar words.

### Problem

when the user deletes the words and the search bar is empty the suggestions still show up. How to remove the suggestions when the search bar is empty?

**Injectable Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
  apiRoot: string = 'myEndPoint';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  search(term: string): Observable<SearchItem[]> {
    // HTTP GET with parameter JSON as mentioned below(inpjson)
    let inpjson = {'keyword': term, 'language': 'en'}
    let apiURL = `${this.apiRoot}?inputAsJson=${JSON.stringify(inpjson)}`;
    return this.http.get(apiURL)
        .map(res => {
          return res.json().conceptOverview.map(item => {
            return new SearchItem(
                item.url,
                item.translatedURL
            );
          });
        });
  }
}
```

**HTTP Response**

```
{
  'searchTyp': 'ExplorativeSearch',
  'conceptOverview' : [
       {
        'url': 'someurl1',
        'translatedURL': 'somestuff1'
       },
       {
         'url': 'someurl2',
         'translatedURL': 'somestuff2'
       }
       ....
   ]
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
class AppComponent {
  private loading: boolean = false;
  private results: Observable<SearchItem[]>;
  private searchField: FormControl;

  constructor(private http: SearchService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchField = new FormControl();
    this.results = this.searchField.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(400)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .do(_ => this.loading = true)
        .switchMap(term => this.http.search(term))
        .do(_ => this.loading = false)
  }

  doSearch(term: string) {
    this.http.search(term)
  }
}
```

[**plunkr link**](http://plnkr.co/edit/f0AOMhNZU9PjJEypy7sn?p=preview)

#### Reference

[HTTP Example with Observable](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do :

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngIf="searchField.value !== ''">
```

Link to : **[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zkkJAo8NPM2iUXiejK89?p=preview)**

Comment: just a quick question, where should I look for in angular in order to autocomplete the search bar upon clicking a suggested query?

Comment: on click of li , get the object

Answer (score 0):

you can use an `*ngif="input.value.length == 0"` on your ul div in your template with inded a `#input` tag inside your input div

Answer (score 0):

Before querying the api, check for the searchTerm, and if it is empty, set the results to an empty array.